# Simple program with std::string is not working

Tags: c++, string

I am learning `std::string` and I want to :

1. Input string
2. Every second letter make Uppercase
3. Output new string

   ```
   #include "stdafx.h" 
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   using namespace std;
   int main()
   {
       string myStr;
       getline(cin,myStr);
       if (myStr.begin() != myStr.end())
       {
           for (auto it = myStr.begin(); it != myStr.end() ; it += 2)
               *it = toupper(*it); 
       }
       cout << myStr;
       system("pause");
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   But after input I am getting error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmZ2B.jpg):

Comment: Start by pressing "Retry" to start the debugger and see where in your code the crash happens.

Comment: Not the problem, but the test `if (myStr.begin() != myStr.end())` doesn't accomplish anything, since the loop condition will eliminate that case, anyway.

Comment: @PeteBecker It's a premature optimization in case the string is empty. And as all premature optimizations is pretty much worthless and not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`it += 2` leads you out of bounds, if the loop ending condition is `it != myStr.end()`. Thus dereferencing

```
*it = toupper(*it);
```

is undefined behavior.

`it += 2` will never give you an exact iterator value of `myStr.end()` as you have for your loops termination condition.

---

As for your comment:

> So how can i fix it ?

Just keep it simple and understandable, like e.g. using something like

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < myStr.length() ; ++i) {
    if(i % 2) { // Every second letter ...
        myStr[i] = toupper(myStr[i]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: So how can i fix it ? Every second letter make Uppercase

Comment: It would - for even-sized strings.

Comment: @SergeyA have u any idea how to make my program work with even-sized strings too?

Comment: @kam_b99, `std::string::iterator` is a [`RandomAccessIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). You can use `it < myStr.end()` instead of `it != myStr.end()` in the conditional.

Comment: @kam_b99 I'm pretty sure at least what I've been proposing works.